# Trying to build view just like text messaging app in android but keyboard is covering up part of recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to basically build the text message view in android, however, I am running into the issue where when the keyboard is shown the enter message edit text view is not "making the recycler view smaller" but instead it is just moving only the edittext view up and overlapping the recyclerview with the messages so the user can't see the rest of the messages when the keyboard is showing.

My message view [image]

My view is supposed to show message 19,20,21,22 but they are covered by the keyboard

Android text message view [image]

The android text message view "makes the recycler view smaller" to show all the messages still when the keyboard is shown and that is what I am trying to accomplish. However, my messages hide behind the keyboard when it is shown.

Activity.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/discussion_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/discussion_empty_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Start a discussion by entering text below"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/discussion_activity_recycler_view"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/discussion_activity_message_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/discussion_toolbar"/>

<include layout="@layout/enter_message_send_view"
         android:id="@+id/discussion_activity_message_view"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="bottom"
         android:gravity="bottom"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/activity_discussion_fab"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/dark_gray"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/discussion_activity_message_view"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down_white_24dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>
```

enter_message_send_view.xml

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:paddingTop="5dp"
         android:paddingBottom="5dp"
         android:paddingStart="3dp"
         android:paddingEnd="3dp"
         android:background="@color/colorWhite">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/join_discussion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Join discussion!"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:id="@+id/discussion_message_section_ll">

    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/seperator"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/seperator_height"
          android:background="@color/dark_gray"
          android:layout_above="@+id/discussion_activity_message_view"/>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/enter_message_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/message_background"
                android:hint="@string/type_here"
                android:layout_weight=".9"/>

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/send_message_image_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".1"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_send_blue_700_24dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your activity element in Android manifest file try to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Like this

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

You can find more details here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html